# Why does MySQL return entries with zeroes when conditioning a string?

Tags: mysql

If I have a column that is of an integer type, and an entry that has a value of `0` in that column, for example something like this:

```
+----------+---------------+----------------+
+ id (int) + name (string) + group_id (int) +
+----------+---------------+----------------+
+ 1        + Albert        + 2              +
+----------+---------------+----------------+
+ 2        + Harry         + 0              +
+----------+---------------+----------------+
```

If I were to query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE group_id = 'string'`, I will get back the result with the `group_id` of `0`

```
+----------+---------------+----------------+
+ 2        + Harry         + 0              +
+----------+---------------+----------------+
```

What does this depend on? It happens with both MyISAM and InnoDB, and it also doesn't matter if `group_id` is allowed to be `NULL` or not.

Can this behavior be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because mysql evaluates strings as `0` when they are cast to an integer type.  Since you are comparing with an integer (id), it automatically casts the string to a compatible type (an integer).

You can test/prove this with the following simple query:

`select cast('string' as unsigned)`

Here you cast the string "string" to an unsigned integer, and the result is `0`

To avoid it:

- Don't compare strings to integers
- OR
- Cast the id to a `string` before the
  comparison.  However, this will have a negative performance impact on
  big results.

Answer (score 0):

When a string can't be interpreted as number ( or if it is not done properly ) it will always return 0.

Also this can be avoided by providing integers or a string that contains only a number.

Answer (score 0):

When it compares the values of `group_id`, which is integer, with a string, MySQL converts both values to floating-point numbers (source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

During the conversion of a string to a number, MySQL stops on the first non-digit character of the string and ignore the rest. If the string doesn't start with a digit then it is converted to number `0`.

> Can this behavior be avoided?

Don't rely on MySQL doing the validation of the input data for you. Since you know that `group_id` is a number, check in the client application the value you use to generate the query and always make it be either a number or a number-like string.